# In IE 8 the quotes around the attributes ex: name,value,id of input element are missing while adding html using jquery append function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

In IE 8 the quotes around the attributes ex: name,value,id of input element are missing while adding html using jquery append function
In IE 8 its is displayed like:

```
<input name=phone value=+91 8765111..
```

The issue is that on displaying the phone only +91 is showing for phone field in IE 8.

What i get in other browsers are like this:

```
<input name="phone" value="+91 8765111"
```

I did searched in google and other sites but no success!

ADD TEL NUMBER FUNCTION

```
function addTelDetails(phone,type,data) {

        var appendCntDiv=   jQuery('#Phone_Tmpl').html();
        var r1=/{:id}/g;
        appendCntDiv=appendCntDiv.replace(r1, counter).replace('{:elemVal}',phone).replace('{:indtelId}',data);
        addHtmlFrmView_Phone(appendCntDiv);

    }
```

TEMPLATE HTML

```
    <div id="multiRow_{:id}_Phone" class="span8 mLft-0">
<input name="telephone[]" id="telephone_{:id}" class="span7 m-wrap margin-bottom-0" value="{:elemVal}" maxlength="30" type="text">  
<select name="data[phone_types[]]" id="telephone_type_{:id}" class="span5 m-wrap">
<option value="1">Home</option>
<option value="2">Work</option>
</select>
</div>
```

ON PAGE LOAD CALLS THIS FUNCTION

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

//getting the json encoded array for existing tel details
        var aTel =  <?php echo $phoneList ?>;
        jQuery.each(aTel, function (i, elem) {
            //call the add tell details on json array
            //params passed are phone, type, individual_phone_id(PK)
            addTelDetails(elem.phone,elem.phone_type_id,elem.individual_phone_id);
            counter++;
        });
}):*
```

Comment: do not use space bertwnn countrycode and number. use +91876 insterad of +91 876. If u still want to use use - instead this is standard format +91-876

Comment: Even google use spaces between numbers we can't force users to enter without spaces.   Google Inc.
1600 Amphitheatre Parkway
Mountain View, CA 94043
USA
telephone: +1 650 253 0000
fax: +1 650 253 0001

Comment: are you sure quotes are missing i tried and they are working check the source code in IE instead of developer tool

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: yes actually i am looping a "json array" of phone numbers and passing the json values to a javascript function ex:appendPhones() which uses a template ex: (having id: phoneTmpl) and replaces patterns within template ex:{:eval} with json values and after replacing all values dynamically, i am using jquery append function ex: (addPhoneDetails) to add the phone content above phone field.

Comment: while looping through content i get quotes around attr value="+91 232323" in chrome and firefox but in IE the same is printed like value=+91 232323 without quotes around value attr. By the way the quotes are missing for id,name attr as well.

Comment: Can you post the jQuery code?

Comment: updated the jquery code in question

Comment: What does #Phone_Tmpl look like? Can you post all of the code being affected/used.

Comment: Chris updated question with all related codes.